# Make a build rotation with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to make a kind of webpack versionning/rotation with build number (with the build's date) and save it.

For example, in my www folder i have :

- src
- build
- backupBuild

Inside my **backupBuild** folder :

- build-01-07-2020
- build-01-05-2020
- build-01-04-2020
- build-01-01-2020

Inside my **build** folder :

- the latest build

I want to keep at least 5 backups (i can change the number of save).

I have no idea how to do this because i don't know exactly how to make a webpack plugin (yes i checked the documentation).

I know how to add a build number :

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __VERSION__: JSON.stringify('12345')
})
```

or with a plugin like html-webpack-plugin / webpack-version-file-plugin

**but i dont know how to *backup* a build**
yarn/npm build always delete the oldest build.

---

Many thanks for your help, do not hesitate to ask questions if i'm not clear.

Comment: Is `build-xx-xx-2020` the output folder or file? If it is a folder, you can simply configure `output` as `output: {filename: OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'build-01-07-2020'), library: A_NAME}`. If it is a output bundle file, then just set `filename` of `output`.

Comment: hello @Wenbo, thanks for your answer. Yeah, i have edited my post.
The build folder is the latest build.
The backupBuild folder is the 5 last builds before, with a timestamp.

Comment: Okay. Then you need to backup the old builds by yourself. 
If you use `npm`, in the `scripts` property of `package.json`, you can hava a `prebuild` command, which happens before `npm run build`. You can write your own logic to backup the old builds. 
Another option is in `scripts` property of package.json, add `node yourBackupScript.js && webpack` to your build command, while `&&` means executing commands in sequence. 

I think you are not going to ask how to backup files here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer thats a great helps i'm gonna try this